# Is it okay to ask a question and answer it as well?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

As per this link from FAQ http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/  - it may not be a bad idea if i ask the question for the very purpose of answering it myself?

However - i would like to reconfirm the views of people in our community.

My specific purpose : we found ruaa, asking various questions all around and got stuck at so many places. It makes more sense that i craft a question that help him get started.

Is this okay?

Comment: Good question! Now answer it! :-P

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is ok to ask and answer your own question, but one must show a bit of restraint as well. To clarify, new users on other busier sites often try to ask and answer what *they* think is an interesting tidbit or a solution to their *localized, under-described*, problem, in the spirit of that blogpost. However, I think that such self-answers will have lasting value only if the underlying issue is well explained and the answer thorough. Self-answers to a hard problem (even if partial) can also help others who are late to the party to know where you're at and give them a spring board to tackle your problem, so to aid that, it needs to be adequate.

In this specific case, I agree that the particular user has been asking several questions in the same vein (sorry, couldn't resist :P) and a canonical question & answer will help. If I may suggest a direction for your endeavor, I would recommend *not* focusing on *their* particular image and problem, but instead on the concepts and theory (and maybe some code, if you're interested) that is necessary to solve their problem — that's what this site is for. That would definitely be a useful resource and we can also close all future identical questions as a duplicate of yours.