# Questions Answered by Editing the Question

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm wondering if there is a community accepted approach to dealing with questions that get answered by editing the question.  (This is different than just [answering one's own question](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-question-and-answer-it-as-well).)

As an example see [SOLVED-Rayleigh Bandwidth Calculation-Radar](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84614/solved-rayleigh-bandwidth-calculation-radar).  My understanding is that the proper way to deal with this would have been for the original poster to have replied to their own question once they resolved it.  How should we handle these cases?  Ask the OP to revert the question and post a response?  Edit the question ourselves and post and answer? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Best is to request that the OP do it.

Let me try that first.

Answer (score 0):

They should be rolled back, probably with a comment asking for a separate answer, since the question and answer must be separate; so each can be voted on independently - a bad question can have a great answer, and vice versa.

Rolling doesn't involve waiting for the OP, and permits someone to answer by the time they have returned. You are not wrong to rollback, it's a correct edit. Where you don't have enough permission for unapproved edits a comment is sufficient, a privileged user can then readily see and rectify the problem.

I think editing the question to remove the answer and then posting it as your own, even with credit, wouldn't be appreciated.